# Delayed expansion inside variable inside for

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to expand some variables inside a for. I don't know how to explain this but I think the code shows pretty well what I want to do.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET arr[0]=C:\Users\me\Desktop\abc
SET arr[1]=C:\Users\me\Desktop\abc2
SET /A arrLastElement=1

CALL :subroutine %arrLastElement% arr
EXIT /B 0

:subroutine
    SET lineToExecute=FORFILES /m "*.*" /c "cmd /c echo !dir!"

    FOR /L %%i in (0, 1, %1) DO (
        SET dir=!%2[%%i]!
        ECHO !dir!
        ECHO !lineToExecute!
    )

    EXIT /B 0
```

Actual result:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\abc
FORFILES /m "*.*" /c "cmd /c echo "
C:\Users\me\Desktop\abc2
FORFILES /m "*.*" /c "cmd /c echo "
```

Expected result:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\abc
FORFILES /m "*.*" /c "cmd /c echo C:\Users\me\Desktop\abc"
C:\Users\me\Desktop\abc2
FORFILES /m "*.*" /c "cmd /c echo C:\Users\me\Desktop\abc2"
```

How should I write this code?

Comment: Perhaps you should set your `lineToExecute` after you have set `dir`

Comment: Yes, one way is moving `set LineToExecute=...` after `set dir=...`

Comment: Similar to the above comments, when you set the variable named `lineToExecute` you're setting it to include an undefined variable. You'll therefore need to escape the expansion of that variable when you set the value, or set the value after having defined the variable named `dir`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a *nested* delayed expansion. There are several ways to achieve it. I think the simplest is this one:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET arr[0]=C:\Users\me\Desktop\abc
SET arr[1]=C:\Users\me\Desktop\abc2
SET /A arrLastElement=1

CALL :subroutine %arrLastElement% arr
EXIT /B 0

:subroutine
    SET lineToExecute=FORFILES /m "*.*" /c "cmd /c echo %%dir%%"

    FOR /L %%i in (0, 1, %1) DO (
        SET dir=!%2[%%i]!
        ECHO !dir!
        call ECHO !lineToExecute!
    )

    EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: I have a couple of questions, though: what do those %%dir%% mean and when should they be used? Why do we have to use CALL <command> for this to work?